# When quoting a quote, does the period go at the end?

Tags: punctuation

“I, Joe Smith, a Director of ABC Company, hereby swear and affirm that the original ‘Unanimous Consent of the Board of Directors By Way of Written Resolution of ABC Company, Passed on February 13, 2000 by circulation’ was presented to the below Notary Public for the State of Texas on ______________ ***, 20***.  The copy attached is a true and correct copy of the original ‘Unanimous Consent of the Board of Directors By Way of Written Resolution of ABC Company, Passed on February 13, 2000 by circulation.’”

Comment: This is off-topic. You might like to ask at the [writers.se] site.

Comment: Have a  look at some of the references here: https://www.google.com/search?q=+%22Passed+by+circulation.%E2%80%99%E2%80%9D&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22period%22+%22double+quotes%22+punctuation&tbm=bks&start=10

Answer (score 0):

The standard rule, as per MLA and common use, appears to be to only quote a punctuation mark where it is used in context, pushing end of sentence punctuation outside of the quote unless present in context.

IE from Purdue's Online Writing Lab:

> According to Foulkes's study, dreams may express "profound aspects of
>   personality" (184).